# Выдает Ошибка 415

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Пишу веб апи, и столкнулся с проблемой что когда заполняю форму данными и нажимаю отправить то сервер выдает ошибку **415**. Просмотрел уже кучу решений, но так и не могу понять от чего это. Думал что это и за CORS(Так и не разобрался как с этим работать, так что если есть возможность то обьясните пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен!)
Вот код контролера

```
[HttpGet]
        
        public IActionResult PostMethod()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        
        public IActionResult PostMethod(UserNames user)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid && user!=null && !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.UserName)))
            {
                
                user.UserName = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(user.UserName);
                user.Id = Convert.ToInt32(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(user.Id));
                string query = @"insert into dbo.UserName values(" + user.Id + ",'" + user.UserName + @"')";

                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("CommandsConnection");
                SqlDataReader myReader;

                using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
                {
                    myCon.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
                    {
                        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        table.Load(myReader);

                        myReader.Close();
                        myCon.Close();
                    }
                }
                
                
                return Content(user.UserName) ;

            }
            else
            {
                return  View("Bed");
            }

        }
```

код модели

```
public class UserNames
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

И Код файла html (использую встроенные .net core html файлы с расширениям cshtml)

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.UserNames
@{
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


    <form id="form1" method="post" 
          enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

        <div>
            <label for="UserName">UserName</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input name="UserName" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="id">id</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input name="id" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`public IActionResult PostMethod([FromForm] UserNames user)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44538773/12888024) и вот это, мне кажется, лишнее `user.UserName = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(user.UserName)`

Comment: Какое же это API если вы отдаете html странички?

Comment: 415 Unsupported Media Type The server will not accept the request, because the mediaType is not supported. Может отправлять то что нужно

Comment: Binding `[FromForm]` отсутствует: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44538773/5752652